# select estimate comboBox,date et time

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

I want selects the contents of a ComboBox, and DateEdit TimeEdit 
This did not work 
it displays only the mat field

```
QSqlQuery qry; 
qry.prepare("select * from Etudiant"); 
if(qry.exec()){ 
    while(qry.next()){ 
        ui->lineEdit_matE->setText(qry.value(0).toString()); 
        ui->comboBox_sexE->setCurrentIndex(qry.value(1).toInt());     
        ui->dateEdit_dateA->setDate(qry.value(2).toDate()); 
        ui->timeEdit_heureA->setTime(qry.value(3).toTime()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting correct values in query? Try outputting them on console or use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
QSqlQuery qry; 
qry.prepare("select * from Etudiant"); 
if(qry.exec()){
    if(qry.next) {
       do{ 
            ui->lineEdit_matE->setText(qry.value(0).toString()); 
            ui->comboBox_sexE->setCurrentIndex(qry.value(1).toInt());     
            ui->dateEdit_dateA->setDate(qry.value(2).toDate()); 
            ui->timeEdit_heureA->setTime(qry.value(3).toTime()); 
        }while(qry.next());   
    }
    else {
    qDebug << "No results found.";
    }


}
else
{
  qDebug << "Unable to execute query."
}
```

You will see if it returns a value.